# How to perform https request with go against incomplete TLS certificate?

Tags: ssl, go, x509

I'm trying to make an https request in go against a URL which has an incomplete TLS certificate chain. Here's the relevant portion from the [Qualys test tool](https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/analyze.html), which shows the certificate chain is missing *"Symantec Class 3 Secure Server CA - G4"* :

[image: SSL report screengrab]

Most browsers do cope with this, presumably because they have the Symantec cert preloaded? A simple golang example, however, will fail with the error `x509: certificate signed by unknown authority`

```
package main

import (
"log"
"net/http"
)

func main() {

    _, err := http.Get("https://www.example.com/")
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    } else {
        log.Println("Success!") 
    }
}
```

I've notified the site in question, but **is there a way I can insert the missing certificate into the certificate store go is using**?

Comment: Fix the server.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To resolve this, I just updated the system certificate store on the client to include the missing intermediate certificate.

The client was running on an Ubuntu based server, so this fixed the issue:

```
#download certificate
cd /usr/local/share/ca-certificates
curl -O https://symantec.tbs-certificats.com/SymantecSSG4.crt

#dump the fingerprint
openssl x509 -noout -fingerprint -sha256 -inform pem -in SymantecSSG4.crt
```

I checked the output matched the fingerprint the test tool reported I was missing:

```
SHA256 Fingerprint=EA:E7:2E:B4:54:BF:6C:39:77:EB:D2:89:E9:70:B2:F5:28:29:49:19:00:93:D0:D2:6F:98:D0:F0:D6:A9:CF:17
```

Then I updated the certificate store with this:

```
update-ca-certificates
```

Comment: Just be aware that this increases risk. The point of intermediates is that the CA can revoke them if they are compromised, but this host would continue to trust it (and considering that we are talking about Symantec here that is not even unlikely). You should fix the server, or let the admins know that the chain is broken if you can't do it yourself.

Comment: That's a good point - this was a situation where a short term fix was necessary on the client side while the the remote server was fixed (which was out of our control)

Answer (score 4):

I recently had a need for this and thought I would share my solution here.  The reason browsers like Chrome can handle this is because they support the AIA extension of X.509, which provides the url to download a given certificates issuing certificate. Chrome then adds the issuing certificate to the chain and retries validation, walking up the path until it runs out of certificates or finds one issued by an approved root CA.

I've made a little library to support this in go.  You can find it here: https://github.com/fcjr/aia-transport-go

Usage is as simple as using the provided custom configured http.Transport:

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "net/http"

    "github.com/fcjr/aia-transport-go"
)

func main() {
    tr, err := aia.NewTransport()
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    client := http.Client{
        Transport: tr,
    }
    res, err := client.Get("https://incomplete-chain.badssl.com/")
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    fmt.Println(res.Status)
}
```